# How to structure firebase DB to block USER from displaying GROUPS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 DB in firebase: `USERS` and `GROUPS` as structured below:

```
USERS
 USERID
   USERNAME
   USEREMAIL
   USERPHONE

GROUPS
 GROUPID
   GROUPNAME
   GROUPPIC
   TIMESTAMP
```

I logged in as `user123`. In the `GroupsViewController`, all the groups will be displayed and I have the option to block/unblock certain group(s). Once it is blocked, that particular group shouldn't be displayed in my `GroupsViewController`.

Now, I wanted to restructure the DB so that the blocked group will not display for that particular user (`user123`). I'm not sure whether to have child node `BLOCKEDUSERS` under `GROUPS` *or* have child node `BLOCKEDGROUPS` under `USERS`, like the below ones.

Which one is best and why? And how to show all the groups except the blocked ones

```
USERS
  USERID
    USERNAME
    USEREMAIL
    USERPHONE
  BLOCKEDGROUPS
    GROUPID

 GROUPS
   GROUPID
     GROUPNAME
     GROUPPIC
     TIMESTAMP
   BLOCKEDUSERS
     USERID
```

I really appreciate your help.

## Update :

I have added blockedGroups under userInfo, added some groupID to specific user.uid and created rules as you can see below. Ideally "groupID2" group should be blocked for the user "6viyeuDpC5TPbO3coElZp3LWWdH3", but the permission is denied for all the users. What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both structure options together if you wanted to start [fanning out your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#fanout).

Using the first option of having a list of `blockedGroups` under the `user` node makes it easy to deny access to groups that the user has blocked by using [Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data):

```javascript
{
  "rules": {
    "groups": {
      "$groupId": {
        ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid)
          .child('blockedGroups').child($groupId)
          .exists() != true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So your database structure would become something similar to:

```
users
 |- userId1
   |- userName: "User 1"
   |- ...
   |- blockedGroups
     |- groupId1: true
groups
 |- groupId1
   |- groupName: "Group 1"
   |- ...
 |- groupId2
   |- name: "Group 2"
   |- ...
```

Where each user ID is a user's `UID` from `FirebaseAuth#getUid()` which will match the currently logged in user to `auth.uid` in the rules. And the list of `blockedGroups` is an index list of group IDs, like in the [flatten data structures documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#flatten_data_structures) example.

---

Unfortunately, the security rule method above won't work as a way to filter the `groups` list, but only as a method to deny access to specific group nodes. This is because [rules are applied atomically top-down](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters).

Instead, you'll need to retrieve the list of `blockedGroups` for the user, and retrieve all the groups, then do a client-side filter to ignore or discard the groups that the user doesn't want to see. Something like this in Swift:

```swift
var blockedGroups = [String]()
blockedGroupsRef.observe(.value) { snapshot in
  for child in snapshot.children {
    blockedGroups.append(child.key)
  }
  updateView()
}

func updateView() {
  groupsRef.observe(.value) { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
      if blockedGroups.contains(child.key) == false {
        // Add to view
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, depending on the requirements for your app, if you don't want to perform client-side filtering, you could flip the group management to be opt-in rather than opt-out, and use a list of `subscribedGroups` instead and then loop through this list to retrieve each group from the database individually by key.

Comment: I have updated the code. I'm getting permission denied for all users.

Comment: @user3310076 Sorry I've just noticed that you wanted to filter the list of groups! This won't work with the security rules I proposed, so instead you'll need to filter the groups client-side. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. In this case, @Aslam's approach also correct. Since I cannot mark both of your solutions as an answer and since you have given me more details, I'll mark yours as an answer. Thanks Again!

Comment: No issues, I am glad you got your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another DB which tracks user based permission. It should maintain all the user-specific permissions, As you are already maintaining the group id, set it as Enable/Disable the flag.

Follow instruction below

1. create DB user_group_permission.
2. Add fields user_id, group_id and status
3. Make status by default 1(consider it as not blocked).
4. When you want to block change the status to 0(consider it as not blocked).

You have to handle this in the code with an enum to make more sense to the value.

The advantage of this module is that later if you add other features other than just blocked and unblock, you will just have to increment status value to 2,3,4 and so on and update the enum.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand this part "As you are already maintaining the group id, set it as Enable/Disable the flag". You mean to say that in my GROUPS DB -->GROUPID, i need to Enable/Disable flag?

Comment: No, I meant that in the new table you can set the Enable or disable. When you start accessing the first check the group id status and then load based groups based on status.

Comment: ok, Thanks, Aslam. I'll definitely implement your approach whenever there is more status than the block. Appreciate your help